# D3js increase space between X axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to increase the space between the labels in the X axis and also the X subgroups I'm using the example provided by D3 documentation [here](https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/barplot_grouped_basicWide.html)

I've been trying to edit this part of the code without look. The `.padding([])` only makes the bar more slim

```
  // Add X axis
  var x = d3.scaleBand()
      .domain(groups)
      .range([0, width])
      .padding([0.2])
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSize(0));

  //subgroups
  var xSubgroup = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(subgroups)
    .range([0, x.bandwidth()])
    .padding([0.05])
```

the idea is to have something like this (this was with excel)
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RULlD.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be able to increase the space between bars without slimming them if you **increase the width of the graph**. without it there is no extra space for moving them so the bars will get slim by default.

In the [example](https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/barplot_grouped_basicWide.html) you mentioned on the top you have width and height options, increase the width and then padding. Eg-

```
  width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


  ....

  // Add X axis
  var x = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(groups)
  .range([0, width])
  .padding([0.2])
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSize(0));

  //subgroups
  var xSubgroup = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(subgroups)
    .range([0, x.bandwidth()])
    .padding([0.2])
```

Working example - https://codepen.io/puneet2412/pen/GRpQKzQ

You can then try to change padding as per your requirement.